# Redshift stored procedure is created but when called, it says column <sp_name> doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have created a stored procedure `stg.sp_l1_l_geography_load()` and I can see it under the stg schema but when I call it using

```
call stg.sp_l1_l_geography_load()
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "stg.sp_l1_l_geography_load()" does not exist
> Where: SQL statement "SELECT  "stg.sp_l1_l_geography_load()""
> PL/pgSQL function "sp_l1_l_geography_load" line 8 at assignment

Why does it even see it as a table/column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in a variable called sp_name that I had initialized with double-quotes

```
sp_name := "*<sp_name>*"
```

Making it single-quotes worked:

```
sp_name := '*<sp_name>*'
```